# no such column: aa (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT note FROM notes WHERE note = aa

Tags: android, sqlite

I try to prevent duplicate
entries in sqlite, 
so i use this code but it gives error 
no such column: aa (code 1)
My DatabseHelper class is:

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
Context context;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_notes";
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(Note.CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Note.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public String insertNote(String note, String address) {
    SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery(" SELECT " + Note.COLUMN_NOTE + " FROM " + 
 Note.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Note.COLUMN_NOTE + " = " + note ,null,null);
    if (resultSet.getCount() == 0)
    {
        values.put(Note.COLUMN_NOTE, note);
        values.put(Note.COLUMN_ADDRESS, address);
        db.insert(Note.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }

    else Toast.makeText(context,note+" already 
  exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return note;
}
public Note getNote(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Note.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{Note.COLUMN_ID, 
Note.COLUMN_NOTE,Note.COLUMN_ADDRESS, Note.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP},
            Note.COLUMN_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    Note note = new Note(
            cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.COLUMN_ID)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.COLUMN_NOTE)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.COLUMN_ADDRESS)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));
    cursor.close();
    return note;
}

public List<Note> getAllNotes() {
    List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Note.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " +
            Note.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Note note = new Note();
            note.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.COLUMN_ID)));

 note.setNote(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.COLUMN_NOTE)));
 note.setAddress(cursor.getString
 (cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.COLUMN_ADDRESS)));
 note.setTimestamp(cursor.getString
 (cursor.getColumnIndex(Note.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));
            notes.add(note);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return notes;
}
}
```

I get This Error

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: aa (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT note FROM notes WHERE note = aa

I get error at this line:

```
Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery(" SELECT " + Note.COLUMN_NOTE + " FROM " +   Note.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Note.COLUMN_NOTE + " = " + note ,null,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

A value needs to be put inside double quotes.

Change your query to this

```
Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery(" SELECT " + Note.COLUMN_NOTE + " FROM " + 
        Note.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Note.COLUMN_NOTE + " = \"" + note + "\"" ,null,null);
```

Comment: it gives new error   android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 when i insert value @Rohit5k2

Comment: @krupagevariya if you use `if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();` and no rows are found, then that would be the result. You should not use `if (cursor != null)` the cursor will not be null, it may be empty. If it is empty then not checking the result of cursor.moveToFirst() (true if the move can be made) and then attempting to access data i.e. `cursor.getInt(column_offset)` then there is no index 0 (first row). hence the exception as you are trying to retrieve data from the first row when there are no rows.

Comment: @krupagevariya you should use something like `if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { .... do your stuff } else { ..... handle no rows found/extracted }`

Answer (score 0):

A [**`SQLite exception`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteException?hl=pt) that indicates there was an error with SQL parsing or execution.

You should add **`SINGLE QUOTE`**.

Add  Single quote here--> `"='" + note + "'"`.

```
 " SELECT " + Note.COLUMN_NOTE + " FROM " +   Note.TABLE_NAME  + "  WHERE
  " + Note.COLUMN_NOTE + "='" + note + "'"
```

**FINALLY**

```
 Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery(" SELECT " + Note.COLUMN_NOTE + " FROM " +   Note.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Note.COLUMN_NOTE + "='" + note + "'",null,null);
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.